# Fixed hamburger icon angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, mat-sidenav

I generated a header component using `ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name header`, in this I need to have the hamburger icon fixed even if the screen size is larger. 
Right now it appears only when screen size is small.
I need some help in fixing this.
Code in stackblitz (https://angular-bfjx3s.stackblitz.io/)
Thank you

Need something like this (https://console.cloud.google.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change *ngIf condition for the hamburger button like this (or you could even remove *ngIf if you want the button to be always visible:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="true">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>web-doctor</span>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

The code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kutmnh

Comment: Thank you,on doing that the toolbar moves to the right now and the backdrop is not working. For smaller screen size the backdrop is working, which means I can click any where on the screen and the hamburger icon collapses.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `*ngIf` condition from below code in **header.component.html**

```html
<button
  type="button"
  aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
  mat-icon-button
  (click)="drawer.toggle()">
  <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the conditional statement `*ngIf="isHandset$ | async"` from button

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for trying,
I found that are different breakpoints as mentioned here ([Angular mat-sidenav property isHandset$ | async explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158521/angular-mat-sidenav-property-ishandset-async-explain/52158682))
So I changed current settings to `((isWeb$ | async) || (isTablet$ | async) || (isHandSet$ | async))` in HTML file and in TS file as follows

```
 isWeb$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Web)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches)
    );

    isTablet$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Tablet)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches)
    );

    isHandSet$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches)
    );
```